# Can Legal Name be used as a token?

Tags: tokens, invoice

I need to use an organization's legal name for invoicing. I have already customized the invoice template for many other fields, but cannot see how to insert Legal Name as a token.

I note this 10 year old forum posting saying that the Legal Name field was not exposed to the token system:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=832.0
Is this still the latest answer?

I know I could add this to my custom field set for organization financial info, but I would rather not duplicate existing field names.

Likewise I can put the Legal Name in the Organization name field, but that renders the Legal Name field redundant (and gives me long, unwieldy org names)

We're running 4.6.24

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/

Comment: I was hoping to do this without hooks since a standard field exists. I'm surprised that this hasn't been an issue before since I would consider any well-formed invoice to be addressed to the legal entity that was expected to pay it. Perhaps I should explore why this field is not exposed to the token system before deciding what to do next.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use legal_name against your message template the best way would be enabling CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY to 1 in civicrm_setting.php

By doing this you can access {contact.legal_name} in your message template

I did made a test against Version 4.7.15 which worked. so please give a try

Reference: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Smarty+in+mail+templates

I guess this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

At least you can use this one: {contact.organization_name}